# Objects in loops and return values

Tags: vb6

I have a function that is similar to this:

```
public sub TestFunction() As Boolean

On Error GoTo NewError:

Dim testObject As New TestObject

For TestVaiable 0 to 1000
  TestObject.TestMethod(TestVariable)

Next

TestFunction = True
Exit function
NewError:
TestFunction = False
End Function
```

I have two questions:
1) Is it bad practice to keep reusing an object in a loop? I don't think it is
2)Is it bad practice to return a boolean (false) if there is an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good practice to reuse a variable in a loop.

It's good practice to reuse an object that will either be in the same state for the whole loop, or have a very simple change that relates clearly to the nature of the loop.

It's bad practice to reuse an object in such a way that it makes it harder to see what's going on with it.

It's good practice to return quickly from a Sub or Function .There's a superstition in VB about returning early that comes from other languages that are irrelevant to it, sort of a computer equivalent to people thinking you shouldn't split infinitives in English because you can't in Latin. It's nonsense.

It's bad practice to just return from a Sub or Function when you encounter an error, without any further handling unless that is the most sensible thing to do for some reason you can explain in a short comment of less than about 200 characters.

It's bad practice not to put in that comment of less than 200 characters explaining why it's okay to just return when that error happened.

Comment: I am use to using exceptions in other languages.  In vb6 if there is an error in TestMethod, I simply write to a log file (for notification) and return false to the calling method (TestFunction).  The database (RDBMS) is then updated to say there is an error.  Is this bad practice?

Comment: That sounds reasonable. Like many questions here there's only so much one can say from the subset of information given, but you're noting the error at both a logging and response level, so while I'm inclined to say `Err.Raise` would be better, this seems like it could be sensible (especially if the caller expects a boolean success value).